# jquery $.each and .html() only showing 1 row

Tags: jquery

Using socket.io on the client and server side.  All's working well there, except in the $.each it's only showing 1 row in the table.

Code:

```
    $('#roll').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        socket.emit('roll', {amount: $('#amount').val(), chance: $('#chance').val()});

        socket.on('roll', function(rolls) {
            $.each(rolls, function(index, roll) {
                $('#rolls').html('<tr><td> ' + roll.id + '</td><td> ' + roll.amount + '</td><td> ' + roll.chance + '</td><td> ' + roll.result + '</td><td> ' + roll.number + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });

    });
```

Comment: This code and your description are insufficient to understand the issue you're facing.

Comment: Well, maybe your data contains only one row? How are we supposed to know? FWIW, it seems rather odd that you call `JSON.stringify(rolls)` to just to call `JSON.parse(rolls)` on it. Just use `rolls` directly. Or would you write `var foo = Number(String(10));` to create the number 10? I hope not!

Comment: You're resetting the entire HTML of the `#rolls` element each time through the loop. Use `append` instead. BTW, the call to `stringify` and `parse` is redundant.

Comment: @c.P.u1 doing that appends all 60 rolls every time there's a new roll.  rolls variable has 60+ rolls stored as JSON, but it's only displaying one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innerHTML of $('#rolls') has been replaced in your each iternation, it is because calling .html will replace all content insides.

Quote from jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

> When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

So, you have to change your code as...

```
$('#roll').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    socket.emit('roll', {amount: $('#amount').val(), chance: $('#chance').val()});

    socket.on('roll', function(rolls) {
        var htmlContent = '';
        $.each(rolls, function(index, roll) {
            htmlContent += ('<tr><td> ' + roll.id + '</td><td> ' + roll.amount + '</td><td> ' + roll.chance + '</td><td> ' + roll.result + '</td><td> ' + roll.number + '</td></tr>');
        });
        $('#rolls').html(htmlContent);
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, or use append instead of html